# Converting netCDF4 data into .CSV format in python 3.8. Does not output desired file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv, netcdf4

I have a single netCDF4 file pertaining to historical average sea surface temperatures around a selected area of the Caribbean. The netCDF4 data spans a wide time scale (from 1850 to 2012) and I am trying to extract a snippet of this data (the decade from 1990 to 2000) and convert it to .CSV format.

So far, my code runs without any errors but it outputs a word document file (not a .CSV file) in my local .py3 directory. Within this file only a single line of text is present with the word ",temperature". ie. no actual data is present.

I am new to python and computer programming in general with nearly no previous experience so I have no clue as to what is wrong with my code. Any help is vastly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
# Converting netCDF4 files to .csv
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Reading in file
data = Dataset('/Users/terrysoennecken/Documents/Fish movement model data/Ocean Temp/adaptor.esgf_wps.retrieve-1628265122.7610238-22900-3-fb77a99c-36ca-48e6-ac6a-2895a39eddd0 2/historical.nc', 'r')
print(data)

tb = data.variables['time_bnds']
t = data.variables['time']
sst = data.variables['tos'] # Sea surface temp
lat = data.variables['latitude']
lon = data.variables['longitude']

# Storing relevant data into variables
time_data = data.variables['time'][:]
lon_data = data.variables['longitude'][:]
lat_data = data.variables['latitude'][:]
temp_data = data.variables['tos'][:]

# Creating a dataframe
start_date = time_data[1971]
end_date = time_data[1825]
time_scale = pd.date_range(start = start_date, end = end_date)

df = pd.DataFrame(1, columns = ['Temperature'], index = time_scale)

# Fnal dataframe save to a .csv file
df.to_csv('Sea Surface Temperature around the Bahamas for the decade, 1990 - 2000')
```

Comment: Post the dataframe so we can better understand

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all this. How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Edit your question above and copy paste a  few lines

Comment: I've just looked into my dataframe and there's nothing in it. There is 1 colum with the title 'Index' and another colum with 'Temperature' but other than that there are no values in said colums.